# How to hide SMTP Auth user mail id in Nodemaile

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer in my project . (sorry for 
My english is not good )

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
service: "Gmail",
auth: {
   user: "agodatest@gmail.com",
   pass: "pwd"
 }
});

smtpTransport.sendMail({
 from: "James andrison <james@andr.com>", // sender address
 to: "user2 surname<receiver@receiver.com>", // comma separated list of receivers
 subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
 text: "Hello world ✔" // plaintext body
}, function(error, response){
 if(error){
   console.log(error);
 }else{
   console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
 }
});
```

In the Above code When I receive mail. I can see Sender name with auth.user email id in the mail but cannot see Sender email id.

I got output like this --> James andrison ;

So can you tell me how to hide SMTP / Auth email id ?

Thankx in advance .

Comment: You want to hide the `from` field when an email has arrived to destination? i don't think you can do that.

Comment: I want to hide Auth username not from field

Comment: have to tried to enter only the email address without `<`,`>`,name .. just the address.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the email output where you're seeing the auth username in the email?